# How to wrote style that will effect on all the items that are in same TargetType?

Tags: silverlight, styles, targettype

I define a style - targetType is 'Line'
I define this style in some grid and i want to make this style effect on any line in this grid.

How can i do it without adding to each of the lines the "stype= {...} " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your style to resources section of your `Grid` or the containing `UserControl` as

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Line}">
```

Comment: this not good for silverlight - this is the solution for WPF.